# In magento quick search the exact product match is displaying in third page and ordering by product title

Tags: search

Suppose I'm searching product using 'Celebrating Silence' which pulls all product whose description, search keywords and product name contains the above phrase. But first I want to display the product whose product name is 'Celebrating Silence' exactly matching and then the other keyword matches. The actual product name 'Celebrating Silence' is showing in 5th page.

Comment: When we faced the same issue for one of the modules, we ended up rewriting the search index to put more "weight" to given attributes like name or description. Will love to see more simple solutions.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I'm using Fulltext + combined search. Product with exact match is not listing on top

Comment: possible duplicate of [What module do I need to improve magento search?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17626/what-module-do-i-need-to-improve-magento-search)

Comment: you might want to withdraw descritpion/short_description from the search, because it's really messing up with all the rest.

Comment: Sounds about right for Stock Magento Quick Search. Sadly, working as designed. Modules are available for Lucene Search which is built into Zend and once you use it you're amazed that it wasn't used in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Check this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/search-type-like-full-text-or-combined), it has a lot of theory.

There are 3 ways to search in Magento: Like, Full Text and Combined, the three with different pros and cons. You can also use Solr and set the attribute relevance in the search, but that is worth another question.

Another good resource is [this](http://www.blueacorn.com/magento-blog/improve-magento-sales-with-better-search-results/) article.

Comment: Using Full Text and Combined. Product is getting searched properly but not able to display the exact product on the top of the list.

Comment: Give the articles i sent you a read, you might find relevant information there.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard not to be sarcastic: IMHO when we talk about three Magento built in search options, then they are bad, poor and sucky. There's handful of third party extensions to remedy this but all they do is that they suck somewhat less. Right now the only alternative you have is to use third party software, such as SolR or Sphinx. Both of them require installation of indexing software and installation of commercial extension.

SolR is out of box supported by Magento EE. There's at least one third party extension that integrates it with CE as well, but my experiences with it is .. well, lets just say that it didn't work out between us. Sphinx is generally considered teensy bit inferior to SolR, but I got it up and running at first try and reindexing was lightning fast compared to SolR. There's also at least one third party commercial extension for Sphinx.

SolR and Sphinx both use some kind of fuzzy logic to determine what to display to a customer and both give pretty good results. Both are able to recognize common typos, such as Magento instead of Magento :), both give results in a fraction of second and both give you exact match as a first result (in case you wonder). Both require however the installation of third party software (not the extension, but full indexing service) and some system level knowledge.

Comment: Lucene is built into Zend and is far better than bad, poor and sucky (your descriptions of the combinations are pretty true to result). The module that enables Lucene search works quite well. Amazing that the Magento team even considered including MySQL "Like" search in the mix as it can't find the seat of its pants with both hands and a flashlight. They had the underlying library for Lucene to work with and it's better than MySQL "Fulltext" any day of the week.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Sounds like something worth investigating.

Answer (score 1):

Magento uses fulltext search and mysql relevance to determine products position in the result set.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html

This is the answer for similar situation:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227030/php-mysql-fulltext-search-order-by-relevance

So you may need to have the product name as a separate column in the index table to put more weight on it.